# jQuery set the selected option

Tags: jquery, postback

I have this form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
   <select name="weeks" id="weeks">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
   </select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

How do I set an option to selected when the form is reloaded? Such as if I select 6 it will be selected for option 6 on reload and then if I switch it to 2 it will have 2 selected on reload?

Comment: You would want some javascript to save the currently selected option to localStorage or a cookie, then retrieve that value when the page loads

Comment: A post sends back a new page - you're going to have to do something server-side to handle returning a selected value - so you'll need to provide details of your server side framework in order to get an answer

Comment: you can use jquery cookie : http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie - to store the value in cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want a persistent behavior you should save the selected state somewhere.
 
you can save it on the server side (db or session) or on the client side (cookie or localStorage).

in case of saving on the client side i suggest using HTML5's [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#localStorage) so just save the selected index (or whatever you need) there and each time you need to reload the page just take the selected index from there and change the select.
here's a sample how to save and get a variable in the client side:

```
function getFoo() {
  var foo = localStorage.getItem('foo');
  if (!foo) {
    setFoo([defaults value]);
    return getFoo();
  } else return foo;
}

function setFoo(foo) {
  localStorage.setItem('foo', foo);      
}
```